# Assign syntax to a file without an extension in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a file `Guardfile` in my rails project, but appears just in plain text, so each time is opened it must be assigned the ruby syntax to display it correctly.
I cannot use `Open all with current extension as...` because it doesn't have an extension, but I suppose I could assign a specific syntax to a file without an extension because files like `Gemfile`, `Capfile` or `Rakefile` are displaying correctly.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I had the same question about the same file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Menu: Preferences -> Browser Packages

Then open the file Ruby\Ruby.tmLanguage

Look up for this block:

```
<array>
    <string>rb</string>
    <string>rbx</string>
    <string>rjs</string>
    <string>Rakefile</string>
    <string>rake</string>
    <string>cgi</string>
    <string>fcgi</string>
    <string>gemspec</string>
    <string>irbrc</string>
    <string>capfile</string>
    <string>Gemfile</string>
</array>
```

Add the new entry:

```
    <string>Guardfile</string>
```

Comment: Could not find the mentioned Ruby package in Sublime 3.

Comment: For Sublime 3 open a Ruby file, then either choose `"Open all with current extension as ..."` from dialog in the the lower right corner, or go to `Preferences -> Settings -Syntax Specific` (opens a file called `"Ruby.sublime-settings"`); add this:
`{
 "extensions":
 [
  "Guardfile",
  "Rakefile",
  "Gemfile",
 ]
}`

Answer (score 3):

Install [facelessuser / ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax).  It has a built in rule for Guardfiles.  It is also good for other random files that should be set as a certain syntax.  For example, here is one I set up for a *random* file that should have Bash syntax.

```
"syntaxes": [
  {
    "name": "ShellScript/Shell-Unix-Generic",
    "rules": [
      {"file_name": ".*random$"}
    ]
  }
]
```

The name value is the path to the tmLanguage file from Packages.  *ShellScript* is the name of the Packages folder that the tmLanguage file is in. *Shell-Unix-Generic* is the tmLanguage file name.

Comment: Great, I'm gonna check that, thanks. BTW, I was checking and it seems that they made a fork of the original project, is compatible with subl 2 and 3 and at least appears in the package control. https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax

Comment: DetectSyntax was removed because the dev is no longer supporting it. The name change to ApplySyntax was requested by the dev (since it's a better description of what the plugin does) when facelessuser took over support.

Comment: I must have installed the original version and the google search brought up the forked version.  I'll replace the link.  Thanks.

Comment: ApplySyntax also support the `{"interpreter": "bash"}` option. Works automagically for my bash scripts without an extension, which were previously recognized as _NAnt Build File_. **AWESOME**.

Answer (score 2):

For Sublime 3:

1. `Commmand + Shift + p`: set syntax ruby
2. Preference -> Settings - Syntax Specific
3. Add syntax like following:

   ```
   {
       "extensions": [
           "Gemfile",
           "Gemfile.lock",
           "Podfile",
           "Podfile.lock",
           "Manifest.lock",
           "Fastfile_helper",
           "Fastfile",
           "Appfile"
       ]
   }
   ```

What really bad is that the syntax does not support fuzzy match, regex thing. This means you must list all the files.